# symfony assetic:dump - Warning: "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you mean to use "continue 2"? (UnitOfWork.php)

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, assetic

I have an issue when dump assetic in my prod environment (php 7.3.14).
In local environment , it's work fine (php 7.2)
The command line are  :

- php bin/console assets:install --env=prod (OK)
- php bin/console assetic:dump --env=prod (KO with warning)

The main issue is some js, image and css not import completely in web folder.

The error is in the file : /var/www/html/demo_project/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php on line 2665

warning :
[image]

More information :
[image]

Thanks for your help

Comment: Although this won't help you, I can tell you that the usage of `continue` changed in PHP 7.3: https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration73.incompatible.php#migration73.incompatible.core.continue-targeting-switch

Comment: Thanks for your info , should I downgrade PHP , or upgrade somes plugins ?

Comment: I don't know your specific setup so I unfortunately can't say, but the [travis](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/3.3/.travis.yml) file for Symfony 3.3 lists PHP 7.2 as the highest tested version. If you can, I'd recommend [upgrading to 3.4](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony4-upgrade/sf34-deprecations), it should hopefully be pretty painless, and will be supported until November 2021. Do it on a staing server, first, obviously. If you really can't upgrade Symfony, then you might have to downgrade PHP however that is in security-fix only mode now.

Comment: well ... technically you should upgrade symfony, but that could include lots of other code changes you mostly have to do manually. as your output suggests, symfony 3.3's end of life was in 2018, so you maybe should at least switch to 3.4. see https://symfony.com/releases for more information about symfony releases.

Comment: ChrisHaas ,Jakumi , thank you very much . Your comments are very helpful for me.I'm going to  think carefully while avoiding a lot of code changes

Comment: assetic was dropped quite a time ago, so indeed, either you'll have to stick to an older version of php, or upgrade and... well drop assetic

Comment: I fixed this with composer update and composer install, there was a composer version this doesn't work on due to the php error but if you manually update composer then do install it works still

Comment: @JasonStephenson what is the version of composer that worked with it ?

Comment: @ALFA the latest is fine, I don't know the exact version - I just know that it required a manual update

Comment: @JasonStephenson okay thanks